# How to get members of abstract class using reflection?

Tags: c#

I have following:

```
var type = typeof(ExampleClass);

public abstract class ExampleClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public abstract class InternalExampleClass
    {
        public string InternalName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I get the value of `Name`, `InternalName`?
I tried to use `type.GetFields()` but it doesn't return `InternalName`
help me, please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Your classes don't have any fields, so the array returned by `GetFields()` is empty. Are you looking for `GetProperties()`?

Comment: @Progman but Name and InternalName are fields

Comment: These are properties, not fields.

Comment: hm, GetFields returns empty, ur right. But GetProperties returns only Name property

Comment: Because the `ExampleClass` only has one property `Name`.

Comment: ok, `InternalExampleClass` is a part of `ExampleClass` so I need to get InternalName too

Comment: You can use `typeof(InternalExampleClass).GetProperties()` to get the properties of the inner class. If you don't know the name, use `GetNestedTypes()` for the inner types.

Comment: oh, thanks for `GetNestedTypes`!

Comment: @Progman is it possible to get values of properties? I can't create instance of abstract class so I don't know what to do

Comment: You can use `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` to get property values from objects, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer all points of your question. But I can give you an idea how to start.

You don't have access to constants, but there is a workaround. First, you need an instance of your abstract class in order to use reflection. Since you can't create an object of an abstract class, you need a class which inherits it. This class contains properties set to the value of your constants.

```
public class InheritedReportAPI : ReportAPI
{
    public string constName { get; } = ReportAPI.Name;
    public string constSignatureBase { get; } = ReportAPI.SignatureBase;
    public string constEventsReportsDeleted { get; } = ReportAPI.Events.ReportsDeleted;
}
```

Then you can use Reflection to get names and/or values of these properties.

```
var inheritedReportApi = new InheritedReportAPI();

var propertyList = inheritedReportApi.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach(var property in propertyList)
    System.Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name}: {property.GetValue(inheritedReportApi)}");
```

The result:

```
constName: reports
constSignatureBase: /report/reports
constEventsReportsDeleted: reports_deleted
```

Comment: hm, I know that I can get fields using```GetFields``` but I can't get classes from abstract class

Comment: for example, I can't get ```abstract public class Events``` from ```abstract public class ReportAPI```